# How to coerce _string-type_ to _fixed-length string-type_ in Go?

Tags: string, go, struct, slice

I have a simple program to open a text file with two space-separated elements per line (first name and last name). Then, I put first-name and last-name in to a struct (T), which goes in a slice of such structs ([ ]T).

There is a catch, first-name and last-name **must** be limited by 20 characters. When reading the text-file, I'm unable to coerce the text to be of that fixed-length. **How can I coerce a general string into a "maximum-20char-string"?**

```golang
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

type T struct {
    fname [20]string
    lname [20]string
}

func main() {
    // Ask for file name (fn)
    fmt.Println("Enter file name, e.g.: 'names.txt'")
    var fn string
    _, _ = fmt.Scan(&fn)

    // Open file
    file, err := os.Open(fn)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    // Create a slice, in which the T constructs will be populated.
    var slice []T

    // Counter for each line
    i := 0

    // Read each line and iterate on it
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        fmt.Println(scanner.Text())
        strline := scanner.Text()
        // words := strings.Split(strline, " ")
        // var words [20]string
        words := strings.Fields(strline)
        // fmt.Println(words, len(words))
        slice[i] = T{fname: words[0], lname: words[1]}
        i = i + 1
    }

    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    // return slice with T-type elements
    fmt.Println(slice)
}
```

In the terminal,

```sh
go build read.go
```

```sh
# command-line-arguments
./read.go:43:23: cannot use words[0] (variable of type string) as type [20]string in struct literal
./read.go:43:40: cannot use words[1] (variable of type string) as type [20]string in struct literal
```

Comment: There's no such thing as "fixed length string type" in Go: `string` is not an array type. You have an array of 20 strings; you can initialize some or all of those 20, but you must say which ones and provide an appropriate number of initializers.

Comment: I would like that `fname` and `lname` be strings of maximum 20 characters. Can I specify that?

Comment: You can write code to check the length, and if too long, reject them. You must write that code yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to need to make various decisions:

- Do you want 20 bytes, or 20 runes?
- What do you want to do with *shorter* strings?
- What do you want to do with *longer* strings?

Once you've made some of these decisions, it is time to write some Go code:

```
func to20bytes(s string) [20]byte {
    ... some code ...
}
```

or:

```
func to20runes(s string) ([20]rune, error) {
    ... some code ...
}
```

for instance.

Since an array of 20 bytes or runes always contains *exactly* 20 bytes or runes, these arrays cannot contain *shorter* "strings" (I put the word "strings" in quotes here as an array of bytes or runes is not a Go string).  In ancient times, people often space-padded arrays of bytes, so that the first function might read:

```
func to20bytes(s string) (ret [20]byte) {
    for i, c := range s {
        if c > 127 {
            panic("non-ASCII-character")
        }
        ret[i] = byte(c) // panic if i >= 20
    }
    for i := len(s); i < 20; i++ {
        ret[i] = ' '
    }
    return
}
```

This function is terrible; see the [playground example](https://go.dev/play/p/jCHyL4eT-27) to see why.  Having an `error` return, or truncating, is probably better, but only you can say; using runes is probably better, but only you can say.